# How do I insert list in nested list

Tags: python, list, insert, append, nested-lists

how do I insert list 'lst'  into the first possition of the 'n_lst'?

```
n_lst = [['I', 'dont'], ['know', 'what']]
lst = ['whatever', 'whatever2']
```

what I need:

```
[['whatever', 'whatever2'], ['I', 'dont'], ['know', 'what']]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Comment: `n_lst.insert(0, lst)`

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Among other things, we expect you to do appropriate research before posting here.  This is already answered in many tutorials on line and in several existing Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new list, you can:

```py
>>> result = [lst] + n_lst
>>> result
[['whatever', 'whatever2'], ['I', 'dont'], ['know', 'what']]
```

If you need to insert `lst` inside `n_lst`

```py
>>> n_lst.insert(0, lst)
>>> n_lst
[['whatever', 'whatever2'], ['I', 'dont'], ['know', 'what']]
```

Comment: the first one works. Thank you. Just the second one: it gives me 'none' Do you know why?

Comment: `list.insert(index, element)` does not return anything (it returns `None`). It updates the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list1.insert(index, list2)`. In your case: `n_lst.insert(0, lst)`.

Comment: I tried. It gives me 'none'

Comment: @KateřinaVeselá - This is because the `.insert()` function returns `None`.  The list is changed in place, so an assignment is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Use insert to do this:

```
n_lst.insert(0, lst)
```